# "Enter Full Screen" Hotkey in wxWidgets

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets 3.1 on OS X 10.11.5.

When I'm adding a ViewMenu like this in my app:

```
wxMenuBar* menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
wxMenu *pViewMenu = new wxMenu("", wxMENU_TEAROFF);
menuBar->Append(pViewMenu, "View");
SetMenuBar(menuBar);
```

An entry called "Enter Full Screen" is automatically added to this menu.
In other apps this Entry has usually an hotkey assigned (`Ctrl+Cmd+F`) to trigger switching to fullscreen.

This is not the case with wxWidgets. Is there a way to have this hotkey assigned? Is this entry generated by wxWidgets or is this done by Cocoa? Can I overwrite this?

Answer (score -1):

heine,

You can use the usual code like:

```
wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
wxMenu *pViewMenu = new wxMenu( "Enter Full Screen\tCtrl+Cmd+F", wxMENU_TEAROFF );
menuBar->Append( pViewMenu, "View" );
SetMenuBar( menuBar );
```

Thank you.

Comment: The String given to wxMenu is shown nowhere. I guess you mean adding a `pViewMenu->Append` entry.  But what is the EventID to use?